# iPhone - How may I scroll a UITextField and resize a UITextView when keybord appears

Tags: iphone, keyboard, uitextfield, scroll, uitextview

I have a UIScrollView inside which I have a UITextField and a UITextView.
I want to prevent the keyboard to hide the field we are working on.
If my user tap on the TextField, I want it to scroll to top of the screen.
If my user tap on the TextView, I want it to resize to the empty place left on the top of the keyboard.
My keyboard has an accessory view (a toolbar).

For now, I catch the UIKeyboardWillShowNotification notification, and I use this code, that does not really work (the textview is resized, but is still behind the keyboard) :
This code worked well when I hadn't the UIScrollView.

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification {

    if ([self.noteView isFirstResponder] == NO) return;

    /*
     Reduce the size of the text view so that it's not obscured by the keyboard.
     Animate the resize so that it's in sync with the appearance of the keyboard.
     */

    NSDictionary *userInfo = [notification userInfo];
    NSValue* aValue = [userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey];                            // Get the origin of the keyboard when it's displayed.
    NSValue *animationDurationValue = [userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey];   // Get the duration of the animation.

    // Get the top of the keyboard as the y coordinate of its origin in self's view's coordinate system. The bottom of the text view's frame should align with the top of the keyboard's final position.
    CGRect keyboardRect = [aValue CGRectValue];
    keyboardRect = [self.view convertRect:keyboardRect fromView:nil];

    CGFloat keyboardTop = keyboardRect.origin.y;
    CGRect newTextViewFrame = self.view.bounds;
    newTextViewFrame.size.height = keyboardTop - self.view.frame.origin.y; // Using bounds here does not help

    NSTimeInterval animationDuration;
    [animationDurationValue getValue:&animationDuration];

    // Animate the resize of the text view's frame in sync with the keyboard's appearance.
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:animationDuration];

     self.noteView.frame = newTextViewFrame;

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

So could you help me to :

- make this work for the textview ?
- make the Textview go back to its original position ?
- How may I do to scroll the TextField without any resizing feature ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you just programmatically scroll the uiscrollview using this:

```
- (void)scrollRectToVisible:(CGRect)rect animated:(BOOL)animated
```

Not sure if this will work for your application or not.

Comment: That doesn't work. Strangely, it seems that the app consider that what is behind the keyboard is visible... Perhaps because keyboardWILLshow